# Google Calendar API - 403 User Rate Limit Exceeded

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, http-status-code-403, rate-limiting

We have a (verified) application integration with Google Calendar API.

For most of our users, it works perfectly fine. However, we have one particular user account that attempts to synchronize our application's calendar with their Google Calendar. The sync fails with the following message sent back to us via our Google libraries:

```
Could not sync events to Google Calendar:\nError calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/REMOVED/events: (403) Rate Limit Exceeded
```

This corresponds to the [documentation on usage limits](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/errors#403_user_rate_limit_exceeded).

We have already raised the per-user quota in the development console twice, and neither time did Google's developer console indicate our users were approaching anywhere near to the number of requests that would have led to an issue; we have bumped it significantly anyway.

The other suggestion on this page is the following:

> If one user is making a lot of requests on behalf of many users of a G Suite domain, consider a Service Account with authority delegation (setting the quotaUser parameter).

Most of users likely do not have a GSuite domain, so this option is off the table.

Are there any other suggestions for how to handle this situation? Is there anything we can look at to resolve this issue for this user? Would using backoff necessarily resolve this situation? We are uncertain if this user's limit is only for their Google Calendar integration with our software, or if it's possible it relates to other Google services the user might utilizing (in which case backoff on our end would not make a difference). How can we determine the best course of action on this issue?

Comment: Depending on how the app is implemented, the quota could be related to the user themselves. The best way to work here would be with the other suggestion in the documentation; using a [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority).

Comment: After more research, there is a public issue reported relating to this, you can check for updates at [this link](https://issuetracker.google.com/141704931), You can still try with the service account approach, but your issue might be related to this.